# InvokeMember using GetField. Field not found in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, reflection

This is probably a simple one but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have a bunch of form items created by the form designer declared as (in frmAquRun.Designer.vb)

```
Public WithEvents btnAquRunEvent1 As VisibiltyButtonLib.VisibilityButton
Public WithEvents btnAquRunEvent2 As VisibiltyButtonLib.VisibilityButton
```

... etc

And I basically want to be able to supply a number to a function access each of these fields. So I wrote this function. (in frmAquRun.vb)

```
Const EVENT_BUTTON_PREFIX As String = "btnAquRunEvent"
Public Function getEventButton(ByVal id As Integer) As Windows.Forms.Button

    Dim returnButton As Windows.Forms.Button = Nothing
    Try
        returnButton = DirectCast(Me.GetType().InvokeMember(eventButtonName, Reflection.BindingFlags.GetField Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Public Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance, Nothing, Me, Nothing), Windows.Forms.Button)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Return returnButton
End Function
```

But it always seems to be generating field not found exceptions.
The message in the exception is  "Field 'ATSIS_ControlProgram.frmAquRun.btnAquRunEvent1' not found.".

The namespace and form name in the message are correct. Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that for `WithEvents` fields, VB actually creates a property that does the necessary event handler attaching and detaching. The generated property has the name of the field. The actual backing field gets renamed to `_` + original name.<sup>1)</sup>

So in order for your code to work just prefix the button name by `_` or use the BindingFlag that corresponds to the property getter (instead of `GetField`).

Alternatively, you can do this a lot easier by using the `Controls` collection of the form:

```
returnButton = DirectCast(Me.Controls(eventButtonName), Windows.Forms.Button)
```

But beware that this only works if the button is top-level, i.e. not nested within a container control on the form.

---

<sup>1)</sup> This is an implementation detail of the VB compiler but it’s portable (especially to Mono’s `vbnc` compiler) since the handling for `WithEvents` fields is described in great detail in the VB language specifications.

Comment: Thanks, setting the bindingFlags to GetProperty did the trick. I didn't know about the Controls object in the form I'll definetely keep it in mind for future reference but the event buttons are in different containers so it would make things a bit complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the event handlers aren't really fields. As compiled they're really properties that implement add_btnAquRunEventX, remove_btnAquRunEventX and fire_btnAquRunEventX methods. There are ways of using reflection to get around this, but that's probably not the best way to approach the problem. Instead you can simply create a List<> and populate it with the event handlers, then index into that list.

I'm a little rusty in VB syntax but it should look something like this:

```
Dim events = New List<EventHandler>()
events.Add( btnAquRunEvent1 )
events.Add( btnAquRunEvent2 )

....

events( 0 )( null, EventArgs.Empty )
```

Take a step back though and evaluate why you're invoking by index. There may be a simpler way of abstracting the whole thing that doesn't involve all this indirection.

Comment: Your description of event handlers is correct but the OP was *not* asking about event handlers but rather about `WithEvent` fields.

Comment: Thanks, I was previously using a method as you described above but I wanted to have a sort of set and forget way of adding / removing buttons from the from designer (as it may in some rare cases need to be edited by people who are not software designers.)

Comment: Well that just highlights my VB wisdom. I thought the WithEvents syntax was basically the same as C#'s event keyword.

Comment: `event` in C# is `Event` in VB. ;-) (Or `Custom Event`, depending on the scenario). `WithEvents` causes VB to auto-wire event handlers without the need to add/remove handlers explicitly.